# When creating a new app project the alloy option does not appear in appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

From the appcelerator studio  I selected file -> new -> mobile app project.
The open dialog appears but does not display the option to create an alloy app.
[These are the only options I can see in New mobile app project  dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTB9Q.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Alloy was not installed in your system for any reason which is quite odd. But here you can install it using command-line/terminal by running this command :

**`sudo npm install -g alloy`**

After successfully installing Alloy, you can check for its version using below command:

**`appc -v`**  mine is Alloy version 1.10.7

You can also check for Alloy installation in your Studio About section as shown in screenshot.

Select **About Axway Appcelerator Studio -> Installation Details -> Plug-ins**

[image]

Comment: Hi Prashant,
Thanks for spenting time for  my answer. actually in my system, alloy is already installed. When I check app -v through CLI it shows as 6.2.4
And also I checked the plugins under Installation details . It is also same as the picture you specified like 2.2.0.149…...

Comment: It should not more than 1.10.x. Do install it again using the command **`sudo npm install -g alloy`**. If it also doesn't work, then download fresh Axway Appcelerator Studio & install it again.

Comment: So, then can't we update the latest alloy version? if so.. am i uninstall the version which is currently having and install the specified version you have mentioned right?

Comment: you just have to run that command to install it, that's al.... restart studio & it should show you Alloy option. If it doesn't, then only reinstall Studio again.